# how to add basic captcha on all sub stores (not only defaul) - open cart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

how to add the **basic captcha** from OC to all the sub stores and ***not only*** for the default one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you are using **Opencart v.2.x**.

You can't! You should use the **Google reCAPTCHA** module instead.
With **Google reCAPTCHA** you can use the same "**Site key**" & "**Secret key**" for more than one domain(s) & subdomain(s).

[image]